# Flask - unittest raising assertionError

Tags: python, flask, python-unittest

I'm reading a book called Flask Web Development. Im currently at unit testing. When I run my simple test it raises an AssertionError. I know it will be something easy, but I just can't figure it out myself. I just dont understand what is going on wrong there.

```
test_app_exists (test_basics.BasicsTestCase) ... ok
test_app_is_testing (test_basics.BasicsTestCase) ... FAIL

======================================================================
FAIL: test_app_is_testing (test_basics.BasicsTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\danie\PycharmProjects\flaskWebDevelopment\tests\test_basics.py", line 22, in test_app_is_testing
    self.assertTrue(current_app.config['TESTING'])
AssertionError: False is not true

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.018s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

My test

```
import unittest
from flask import current_app
from app import create_app, db

class BasicsTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app = create_app('testing')
        self.app_context = self.app.app_context()
        self.app_context.push()
        db.create_all()

    def tearDown(self):
        db.session.remove()
        db.drop_all()
        self.app_context.pop()

    def test_app_exists(self):
        self.assertFalse(current_app is None)

    def test_app_is_testing(self):
        self.assertTrue(current_app.config['TESTING'])
```

and config.py

```
    import os
    basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    
    class Config:
...
        @staticmethod
        def init_app(app):
            pass
    
    class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
        DEBUG = True
        SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'data-dev.sqlite')
    
    class TestingConfig(Config):
        DEBUG = True
        SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite://' # only store info in temp memory
    
    class ProductionConfig(Config):
        SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'data.sqlite')
    
    config = {
        'development': DevelopmentConfig,
        'testing': TestingConfig,
        'production': ProductionConfig,
        'default': DevelopmentConfig
    }
```

unit test launcher command:

```
@app.cli.command()
def test():
    import unittest
    tests = unittest.TestLoader().discover('tests')
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(tests)
```

Comment: Why did you use CamelCase for `TESTING`?

Comment: it was like that in book, but even if i type it in lowercase it still does the same thing